# MATLAB semilog scaling

Tags: matlab, logarithm, exponential, pitch-detection

I'm new to MATLAB, and am working on a program that deals with frequency of the human voice based on microphone input. The biggest problem I am running into is that musical notes (what I am dealing with in this project) increase in frequency exponentially, about 1.059463^x for each semitone in the musical scale.
In the program I am dealing with, I need to both scale the graph so the detected frequency is close to the note number it corresponds to as well as scale the data so that I can work with the note numbers in terms of notes and musical cents so the frequency graph can be converted easily to MIDI data. 
The only other option I have found has been to create a library of frequencies for the recorded frequencies to be compared to, but that is unnecessarily complicated and time consuming. 
So, in essence, I am trying to scale the data so that A2, with a frequency of 110Hz, would correspond to its note number 45. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [This](http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html) may be of help

Comment: I've actually been using that as a reference, but I don't know how to scale the data to the MIDI scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
f = 110; %// frequency in Hz
n = log10(f/440)/log10(2)*12+69; %// 440 Hz (note A4) is note 69
note = round(n);
cents = round((n-note)*100);
```

Examples: `f = 110` gives

```
note =
    45
cents =
     0
```

`f = 345` gives

```
note =
    65
cents =
   -21
```

in accordance with [this reference](http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html) and [this converter](http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/music/note/).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to scale an entire graph using this? For example, if using real-time microphone input, is there a way for the detected frequency to be displayed and recorded in terms of note number and cents rather than just the frequency?

Comment: "_the __detected__ frequency to be __displayed__ and __recorded___". Sorry, I don't get what you mean. The recorded audio file contains audio samples representing the waveform. Detecting frequencies from that (and then displaying them) is a different matter

Comment: I have a pitch detection algorithm that I can use, but I need a way to easily convert the frequency that program detects into the MIDI note number. Essentially, if I get 4 data points f=110, f=116.541, f=123.471, and f=103.826, I would want the resulting graph to display the note number rather than the frequency, giving me the data points n=45, n=46, n=47, and n=44.

Comment: Well, my answer converts those `f` into those `n` (variable `note` in my code). So what's the problem?

Comment: Can I convert an entire series of data points in a graph at once using the same method?

Comment: Yep, my code is vectorized. Try it with `f=[110 116.541 123.471 103.826]` and you will get  the four values `[45    46    47    44]` in variable `note`.

Comment: I'm sorry if this question seems obvious or redundant, but could I call the entire function of the frequency over time into the `f=[]` portion of the code? In pseudocode, this would look like `f=[frequency(t)]`

Comment: Yes, `f` can be any vector or array of numbers. Do give it a try and see for yourself!